# How to use log4j2 to logging entire application?

Tags: log4j2, apache-tiles

I am not sure whether I have integrated my application correctly with log4j2 but my objective is very clear. I want to capture each and every tiny `logging information` in my log file. The `logging information` includes the `spring framework loading + apache tiles loading + my app loading and runtime logging.`

Although I am able to capture `org.springframework` logging details but unable to do so for `org.apache.tiles.` However, I do capture all the logging information in my console.

It's not like that didn't capture anything at all from tiles logging, I do capture but it's ver few logging information. The amount of logging information I can see in the console is not even little close in the log file.

Here is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">D://log/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="LOGFILE" fileName="${filename}/SpringWebJsp.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.jio.tiny" level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="LOGFILE" level="info" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" level="info" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.tiles" level="debug" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <!--<Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="debug" additivity="true"> 
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" level="debug" />
        </Logger> -->
        <!-- <Logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" level="info" />
        </Logger> -->
        <!-- <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" level="info" />
        </Logger> -->
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jio.tiny</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringWebJsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringWebJsp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <apachetiles.version>3.0.5</apachetiles.version>
        <apache.logger.version>2.8.2</apache.logger.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>io.spring.repo.maven.release</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j2 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.logger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.logger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.logger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.logger.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
             <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- <version>3.2</version> -->
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>SpringWebJsp</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            D://log/jars/
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringWebJsp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

logging for tiles captured in console

```
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.504 [tomcat-http--2] sax - setDocumentLocator(com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy@261c3a65)
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.504 [tomcat-http--2] sax - startDocument()
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.504 [tomcat-http--2] sax - resolveEntity('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN', 'http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd')
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.504 [tomcat-http--2] Digester -  Resolving to alternate DTD 'jar:file:/D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringWebJsp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-3.0.5.jar!/org/apache/tiles/resources/tiles-config_3_0.dtd'
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.506 [tomcat-http--2] sax - startElement(,tiles-definitions,tiles-definitions)
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.506 [tomcat-http--2] Digester -   Pushing body text ''
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.506 [tomcat-http--2] Digester -   New match='tiles-definitions'
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.506 [tomcat-http--2] Digester -   No rules found matching 'tiles-definitions'.
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.507 [tomcat-http--2] sax - ignorableWhitespace(

    )
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.507 [tomcat-http--2] sax - ignorableWhitespace(
    )
.
.
Similar piles of log continue
.
.
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.540 [tomcat-http--2] BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - File Resource file:/D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringWebJsp/WEB-INF/views/tiles/tiles_en.xml at file:/D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringWebJsp/WEB-INF/views/tiles/tiles_en.xml not found, continue
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.540 [tomcat-http--2] BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - File Resource file:/D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringWebJsp/WEB-INF/views/tiles/tiles_en_US.xml at file:/D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringWebJsp/WEB-INF/views/tiles/tiles_en_US.xml not found, continue
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.654 [tomcat-http--2] ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - Resolve definition for child name='home' extends='base-definition.
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.654 [tomcat-http--2] ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - Resolve definition for child name='products' extends='base-definition.
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.654 [tomcat-http--2] ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - Resolve definition for child name='contactus' extends='base-definition.
[DEBUG] 2017-07-04 22:02:57.661 [tomcat-http--2] BasicTilesContainer - Render request received for definition 'home'
```

The amount of logging that my log file able to capture is just the last six lines of the above log details.

I wonder if the behavior is ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The amount of logging information in the console is not even little
>   close in the log file. Is this behavior ok?

**Yes.**

According to your configuration file, you are writing logs of only 3 packages (`com.jio.tiny`, `org.springframework` and `org.apache.tiles`) in log file. But every log (with level `debug` or higher) are being written in console, including logs of mentioned 3 packages. So it is expected that console may have more logs than file.

> Is it possible to set the console and log file to have same logs? How?

Remove extra `Logger` definitions from `Loggers` section and refer file appender along with console appender. So, to have same logs in console and log file, your `Loggers` section can be as follows:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        <AppenderRef ref="LOGFILE" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although your answer is matched to my requirement, I wonder if it is still possible to manage logging at the package level?

Comment: Try referring `LOGFILE` wherever you're referring `STDOUT` and vice versa.